# Problem with resolution format in a responsive iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

hi i have a problem with my google form format in my site that need to work with a resolution of 1280x800 , i´m using chrome console to see the resolution but the form height is creating a scroll bar at the side and i want to fit it to my resolution is any solution or fix?? it need to fit the 1280x800 format .txs

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
html, body, .main, .main iframe {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.main iframe {
    border: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="main">
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd4pzJ9kRydc-UVkEkm9xKDZjF0S3Earn-Wjcbh8FEAlYnkXA/viewform?embedded=true" frameborder="0" marginheight="0">Loading...</iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what are you trying to achieve? There's a vertical scrollbar, which is completely normal since the content in the iframe overflows iframes height.

Comment: is it possible to get the content in a full page without the scroll?

Comment: because this is for a tablet that the resolution is 1280x 800 the problem is that the scroll doesn't work on it its for a static pag

Comment: the big problem is that the form doesn't get more width if that stretch i didn't had this problem, i need to get it to fit on this resolution

Comment: The Google form is being loaded inside an iframe. Along with the form, its loading its own stylesheet. It just happens (design decision) that Google decided to limit forms width to 600px. You are unable to override that with your own stylesheet. So you will need to find a way to load the form without using iframes. Check this: https://blog.webjeda.com/google-form-customize/

Comment: txs anyway i tried the way the site says but because its radio bottoms  and no inputs so i cant use it because i cant get the names in the code ( like this it from the last part of the form were i ask for the comment "name="entry.91425745" ")